# HTTP Response 503, however site works

Tags: facebook, http

At this moment I'm working with the Facebook API; I Need to fill in a Privacy Policy, so I did. However, after some research I discovered that the HTTP Response code will always be 503, But I can't find out why. The page is there, and when visiting it in a Browser it works, with no problem at all. Running a check, shows me that the page returns a 503 to facebook and any other request (For example. https://httpstatus.io/).

I use cloudflare, nothing more. Why am I getting a 503 Response, but the page is just working fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to have 503 only when robot is visiting the page. Try to simulate Facebook User Agent from your browser or rest client.

You can check Facebook user agents on developers facebook page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler

Cloudflare could be the cause of your problem, because it blocks bad robots (Facebook should be good robot). Try to disable it and see if it works. If this is the problem, you need to contact Cloudflare support.

Comment: Thanks. This indeed was my problem. I checked Cloudflare again and again, and found the Issue, Something about the HTTP Header Integrity. This option needs to be disabled.

Comment: Disabling this feature is making your site less protected. Read more about it, you have other options. Don't hasitate to contact cloudflare support. More details: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170086-What-does-the-Browser-Integrity-Check-do-